# What would the climate of this map look like?

Tags: science-based, climate, earth-like

In this scenario, there is a binary star system comprised of one naturally-made star and another made by the hands of some mysterious hyperadvanced civilization.  The latter is a white giant, an artificial, unnatural star that is pretty much a white dwarf scaled up to 1,500 times as wide as our sun (temperature and luminosity, apparently, is tied to the stellar equivalent of the Square Cube Law.)  But because of its inactivity and inability to emit radiation, it can shine for trillions of years rather than just a few million.  But the former is a natural star, a K5 orange dwarf star, 74% as wide, 69% as massive and 16% as bright as our sun. Such stars burn their hydrogen so slowly that they can last not for ten billion years like our sun, but 34. And they are so hot that they can have a habitable zone that isn’t close enough to tidally lock their planets, which would defeat the purpose of habitability in the first place. Another, equally important, factor about orange dwarves is that they emit very low quantities of ultraviolet radiation. And with this star orbiting the white giant, the planet orbiting only the orange dwarf (in an S-type orbit) won’t have to worry about getting too dark or too cold.

Here is the map of the planet.  (Also, since it was crafted by the hyperadvanced civilization rather than nature, its elevation colors are accurate.  Green represents sea level and white represents the height of Mount Everest.)

[image]

And here is how it looks in comparison to Earth, because latitude is very important:

[image]

It is identical in every way to our Earth-Moon cycle, but with the following differences:

- 91% of Earth's gravity
- Atmospheric thickness of 370 miles
- Rotation of 26 hours
- Revolution of 417 rotations
- CO2 content:  4500 ppm
- O2 content:  35%
- Axial tilt: 19.7-26.9 degrees in a 21,500-revolution-cycle

All said, what would the climate look like on this planet?

Comment: / because of its inactivity and inability to emit radiation, it can shine for trillions of years /  I am confused about what the white giant is doing.  Is it emitting radiation?   I think yes because it is shining and because of its presence, the planet /  wont have to worry about getting too dark or too cold / .  How does the white giant compare to our sun as regards luminosity etc?

Comment: You didn't watch Kursgastz's video on white dwarves?

Comment: Nope.  Link it up and I will.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsN1LglrX9s

Comment: VTC:NMF. Climate of an entire planet violates the book rule. Worse, you know the basics: hot at the equator, cold at the poles. Wet on the coasts, dry in the intrerior. You have a lower % of water-to-land, so less rainfall & more desert. Local variations based on variables far too detailed for an SE question. Climate Qs are the most difficult on this Stack and often the most often closed for lack of details (where are the rivers, lakes, aquifers, fertile soil vs. rocky soil..., ocean currents, etc., etc., etc.). Consideing we have just one datapoint to work with, this is too vague to answer.

Comment: It's already focused on one problem!  Why close it for something you want that it has?

Comment: Focused on one problem... The [help/dont-ask] states, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Searching for "climatology" on Amazon displays almost 1,000 books - and that's only the books they list. You've been on this stack a long time, John. No one should have to tell you when your question is ridiculously too broad (aka *unfocused.*)

Comment: This didn't stop you from leaving similar questions open.

Comment: @JBH There's been many questions about world climates when given a map to work with. Consider [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102798/how-do-i-figure-out-my-planets-biomes-and-weather), for instance, or [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/151283/does-my-climate-map-work): left open, upvoted with multiple answers, etc., and those are just two examples. This question supplies at least as much detail than either of those. Too many such questions have been deemed on-topic to reasonably close this one: climate is a broad question, but only one.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I don't have time to supply a full answer, and it's worth noting that your altitude map isn't obvious enough to easily figure out precise heights. I'd suggest recolouring your map with clear divisions (so try to avoid "gradient of green shades") at least every 1000 metres and supplying a suitable colour key. However, I can point you to my answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102798/how-do-i-figure-out-my-planets-biomes-and-weather/102838#102838), which is basically a how-to guide for working out the details yourself.

Comment: @Palarran Those two examples are both over three years old. It is the policy on every Stack in Stack Exchange that old questions are not a precedent allowing for violation of current rules and policies. The simple reality is that this question violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I don't see every question that comes through this Stack, so the assertion is meaningless. I VTC every "what's the climate of my entire world" question I come across. It's hard enough to get *one aspect* of climate past me, it's that complex. If you're looking for a general simplification, then create something and move on, it's as good as any other answer. If you want specifics, you need to be specific.

Comment: The major problem with increasing the diameter of a white dwarf is that implies increasing mass. As soon as that mass goes beyond about 1.33 $M_{sun}$ It will cease to be a white dwarf as it will collapse into a neutron star. Known white dwarfs range from 0.17 .. 1.33 $M_{sun}$ and neutron stars are typically 1.1 .. 2.1 $M_{sun}$.  So one of the major details of the question is not science-based plausible.

Comment: @JBH  Ahem:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230843/what-would-the-climate-of-this-habitable-world-be-like?rq=1  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186109/what-will-my-alternate-earths-climate-be-like-basically-speaking-not-asking?rq=1

Comment: @JohnWDailey Previous questions are not precedent for breaking current rules (on all Stack Exchange sites). I voted to close both for the same reason.

Comment: @JBH  And yet they remained open.  And what do you mean by "current"?

Comment: @JohnWDailey You misunderstand. When you brought them to my attention two comments ago and used them as a precedent I went then and cast my vote to close them. "Current," of course, means today. Although the question from five months ago should have been closed then for violating the book rule.

Comment: @JBH  What rule?  This has never been forbidden before.

Comment: What rule? [help/dont-ask]: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." You're asking for the climate of *an entire planet.* Not just the currents, or the wind, or the temperature gradients. *Everything for an entire planet.* Entire *college degree programs* exist for this kind of question. ***And I cited that rule in my first comment.***

Comment: And just to make a point. You've asked ***EXACTLY*** this kind of question twice before (thanks for providing those links). What have you failed to learn from the answers to those questions that you require asking the question *again?*